# Burn Elevation Points in DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem

I have Digital Elevation Model (DEM) and elevation points collected from field survey. Now I want to add these elevation points into DEM.

In other words I want to burn these points into DEM. How would I do that in ArcGIS 10.2?

Comment: Please clarify "burn these points into DEM"?

Comment: Would something like Luke's answer in [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18596/86909) exchange work for you? You could [convert the points to raster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/point-to-raster.htm) and then apply the same algebra expression.

Answer (score 5):

convert your point to raster with "feature to raster", making sure with the environment variables that you have the same pixel size and extent than your DEM.

you can the use "raster calculator" (map algebra) to create a new raster (ArcGIS standard extensions do not allow you to "edit" rasters, it creates new ones).

```
Con(Isnull(rasterizedPoints), DEM, rasterizedPoints)
```

will replaced all values of your DEM with the values of your points (where they exist)

Comment: This only replaces the values in DEM which i created from points data. How can i replace my points data in origional 30*30 m resolution DEM.

Comment: you mean that you want to create a new DEM with the new points ? I tought that I understood your question but it seems not.